# The underlying mechanism in 'yield return www' of Unity3D Game Engine

Tags: unity

In the Unity3D game engine, a common code sequence for getting remote data is this:

```
WWW www = new WWW("http://remote.com/data/location/with/texture.png");
yield return www;
```

What is the underlying mechanism here?

I know we use the yield mechanism in order to allow the next frame to be processed, while the download is being completed. But what is going on under the hood when we do the `yield return www` ?

What method is being called (if any, on the WWW class)?
Is Unity using threads?
Is the "upper" Unity layer getting hold of www instance and doing something?

EDIT:

- This question is specifically about Unity3D internals. I'm not interested in explanations of how `yield` statement works in C#. Instead, I'm looking for an inside view of how Unity deals with these constructions, to allow, for example, to WWW to download a piece of data in a distributed manner across several frames.

Comment: Note that using `yield return` for asynchronous operations is a hack.  In a "real" C# program, you'd use a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this.  Unity is probably not using them because it was created before .Net 4.0, when `Task` was introduced.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the C# [yield keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in action - its not doing anything special with the `www` object, rather its means something special for the method its contained in.  Specifically this keyword can only be used in a method which returns an `IEnumerable` (or `IEnumerator`), and is used to indicate what object will be "returned" by the enumerator when [MoveNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx) is called.

It works because the compiler converts the entire method into a separate class which implements `IEnumerable` (or `IEnumerator`) using a state machine - the net result is that the body of the method itself is not executed until someone enumerates through return value.  This will work with any type, there is absolutely nothing special about `WWW`, rather its the containing method which is special.

Take a look at [Behind the scenes of the C# yield keyword](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/behind-the-scenes-of-the-c-yield-keyword/) for some more insight into what sort of code the C# compiler generates, or just experiment and inspect the code yourself using something like [IL Spy](http://ilspy.net/)

---

**Update:** To clarify

- When Unity calls a coroutine that contains a `yield return` statement all that happens is that an enumerator is returned - none of the method body is executed at this point
- To get the method body to execute Unity must call `MoveNext` on the iterator in order to get the first value in the sequence.  This causes the method to execute up to the first `yeild return` statement, at which point the caller resumes (and presumably Unity goes on to render the rest of the frame)
- As I understand it Unity normally then goes on to call the `MoveNext` method on the iterator once each subsequent frame, causing the method to execute again up to the next `yield return` statement once each frame, until either the end of the method or a `yield break` statement is reached (indicating the end of the sequence)

The only special bit here (and in a [couple](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) of [other cases](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WaitForFixedUpdate.html)) is that Unity doesn't advance this particular iterator the next frame, instead it only advances the iterator (causing the method to continue executing) when the download has completed.  Although there does appear to be a base [YieldInstruction](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/YieldInstruction.html) class which presumably contains a generic mechanism for signalling to Unity when an iterator should be advanced, the `WWW` class doesn't appear to inherit from this class so I can only assume that there is a special case for this class in the Unity engine.

Just to be clear - the `yield` keyword doesn't do anything special to the `WWW` class, rather its the special handling that Unity gives to the members of the returned enumeration which causes this behaviour.

---

**Update the second:** As for the mechanism that `WWW` uses to download web pages asynchronously it probably uses either the [HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx) which will internally use [asynchronous IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365683%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or alternatively it could use threads (either creating a dedicated thread or by using a thread pool).

Comment: Actually, in Unity, something special does happen to a `WWW` object when it is yielded, see [`WWW`'s reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html).

Answer (score 9):

`yield` seems to be mainly used in Unity in a coroutine context. To read more about coroutines and why they use C#'s `yield` I recommend this blog article: [Unity3D coroutines in detail](http://altdevblog.com/2011/07/07/unity3d-coroutines-in-detail/). Most of the research in this answer comes from that article.

Coroutines in Unity are used to encapsulate tasks which:

1. May take longer than a frame to be rendered (thereby causing slowdowns), and
2. Can be performed separately from the game loop (because the result does not need to be available for the current frame).

Examples of these kinds of tasks are pathfinding (re)calculations or, as is the case in your question, getting data from a website.

To answer your subquestions (in a slightly modified order):

> What method is being called (if any, on the WWW class)? Is the "upper" Unity layer getting hold of www instance and doing something?

Unity's `WWW` class is designed to be yielded from a coroutine. According to the comments on the blog article linked above, the speculative block of code (the '"upper" layer') about `YieldInstruction`s actually contains a switch which also checks for yielded `WWW`s. This code then makes sure the coroutine will finish automatically when the download is done, as described in [`WWW`'s reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html).

> Is Unity using threads?

In this case, to download the data "without blocking the rest of the game": yes, most likely. (And threading is definitely used to decompress the downloaded data, as evidenced by [`WWW.threadPriority`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW-threadPriority.html).)

Comment: nice! I saw the comment http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/07/07/unity3d-coroutines-in-detail/#comment-245327432 and it seems that WWW is treated specially. So I'd like to know how this is accomplished, in order to allow the download to be made across several frames, without using threads?

Comment: Good point! I suppose there must be some threading going on at that level after all, I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @thyandrecardoso I'd guess it uses [HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx) or similar, however you could decompile the assembly to confirm this if it really mattered to you.

Comment: for now, I'm really only waiting for the "best explanation"... would be great if anyone from Unity dev team gave the "correct answer" 8-)... ultimately, I think the real implementation won't be far off the ones already given here... I don't have an actual need to decompile the assembly and know all this for sure though. But I might try it later :)

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, WWW is implemented internally as native code, meaning that we can't look at the code. From experimentation I can say that

1. `WWW` is *not* derived from `YieldInstruction`, so whatever happens when you `yield` it must be handled by special-case code.
2. I've never obseved any difference between

   ```
   yield return www;
   ```

   and

   ```
   while(!www.isDone)
       yield return null;
   ```

   I think that's the most logical way to implement it, and *most probably* that's what is going on under the hood. But I don't know for sure.
3. Unity does *not* start a new thread for downloading, at least on some platforms (iOS, webplayer). Or if it does, it sets `WWW.isDone` on the main thread. I know this because this code:

   ```
   while(!www.isDone)
       Thread.Sleep(500);
   ```

   doesn't work.

I don't think you can have more specific answers unless someone with access to Unity3d's source code comes here.

Comment: Yup. Really nice insights! Thanks! Even though not launching a thread per se, the most probable thing that might be happening is WWW (or the engine layer) using HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse (or something like it)... right? Something completely async must occur either way... the download can't be "paused".

Comment: ** can't be "paused" between frames, I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Since Unity3D uses C# as their scripting engine I suppose its the standard [yield keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is built into C#. Basically what it means is that it returns the value of www already so that you can continue while the next iteration it will return the next value, etc... Yield basically creates a state machine and iterator in the background.

Comment: Yes, I think I have the basic notions about the yield keyword. However, what is happening during the constructor of WWW that allows for that "state machine"? I mean, "yield return www" does not seem to be calling anything inside the WWW class... When you say "it means is that it returns the value of www already", what is the www instance value? What will that instance do on the next "iteration" ?

Comment: In Unity coroutines, yielding WWW is a special case, see [`WWW`'s reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html). Furthermore, I'm not sure `yield` creates anything. The iterator context is created by implementing `IEnumerable` or using it as a return type. "State machine" seems off too. Sure, there is state, but that alone is not a sufficient property, right? Maybe you could elaborate on that.

Comment: Here is a good reference on the normal C# behavior. http://shadowcoding.blogspot.nl/2009/01/yield-and-c-state-machine.html . Yield generates a lot of code to keep track of where it is in the iterator. About Unity's special case yielding WWW, I didn't know but according to the docs it doesn't have anything todo with the normal C# keyword, that's very confusing, they could'be just made it an async method.